# Butterknife OnClick with TabLayout

Tags: android, butterknife

I just got a hold of Butterknife and have been trying my best to standardize all of my 'OnClick's to be bound via Butterknife.

I have found though, that it's difficult to follow Butterknife's standard binding pattern when dynamically populating views (via adapters for example) since the individual views don't have id's

```
 @OnClick(What Do I put here if I have no ID?)
    public void OnClickMethod(View view) {
    //Body
    }
```

Specifically, I'm having problems adding onClicks to views that are part of a TabLayout. I know I can use the built in

TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener()

But ideally I'd like to be consistent in binding all forms of onClick via Butterknife. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/javadoc/butterknife/package-summary.html

It does not look like it's supported yet

Answer (score 0):

Set an id in res/values/ids.xml like :

```
<item name="my_view" type="id"/>
```

And then add the id to the view  :

```
myView.setId(R.id.my_view);


@OnClick(R.id.my_view)

public void OnClickMethod(View view) {
//Body
}
```